# Minimum distance algorithm in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to find out minimum distance between duplicate items in a list. Here is my code :

```
A = [3,2,1,2,3,5,6]

def min_distance(A):

  for i in range(len(A)):
     distance = len(A) - 1     
     for j in range(i+1, len(A)):
         if A[i] != A[j]:
            continue
         else:
            min_distance = abs(i-j)
            distance = min_distance if min_distance < distance else distance

  return distance if distance > 0 else -1

min_distance(A)
6.
```

It is not working as expected. It should return 2. There are 2 duplicate values in the list 3 and 2. The distance between duplicate 3's is 4 and between 2's is 2. So, it should return 2. But, it is returning 6.

Any help on this highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be reinitiallizing `distance` in each pass through the outer loop. Is that what you want?

Comment: OK, I figured it out.  Thanks for help.

Comment: FWIW: `min_distance if min_distance < distance else distance` → `min(min_distance, distance)`…